# Load test makes my api timeout and crash restarting

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, load-testing

I am doing a load test on my database with 10 million records on main entity I am doing test and 60 million records on subentites(linked with foreigh key), with really simple quick app and doing simple call to API endpoint GET. I am getting one row with same ID constantly. Practically there is nothing specific in code, just SELECT call with repo:

```
    public async Task<Package> GetSingleAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Package>(id);
    }
```

Now the thing is, I get this error constantly:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

I tried to scale my database up and my web service app up as well, with no change. I am doing 5 minute long load test with 30 users constant load, which would do on average 30 requests per second.

Another thing is, my app which does query is crashing and restarting every 20 seconds:

> 11:46:50 19-Jul   DataPlatform    RD00155D622BC3  [Application_Start]
>   Instance starting on machine RD00155D622BC3
>   11:46:28 19-Jul   DataPlatform    RD00155D622BC3  [Application_End] Instance ending
>   on machine RD00155D622BC3. The reason is: InitializationError

How could I troubleshoot this? My thought is to increase instance and plan even further, anything else?

Comment: Have you ran any kind of analysis on your database, reviewed the execution plans of your EF queries etc? You might need to add additional indexes in order to make the system more performant.

Comment: What kind of analysis? I was thinking about Azure SQL Database Query Performance Insight. Is there anything else old school way? I am kind of in loop now. Can't find the issue.